# App is not visible after after full rollout on google play store

Tags: android, google-play, publish, google-play-console

I have released a mobile app on production on 23rd of march and it does not fall in the review process and it's status directly turn into "Available on google play (Full Rollout)" but my app is not visible on google play store it's been almost 6 days and yes I have released the mobile app for internal testing after passing that test I uploaded it to production. Attached are inbox, release overview, publishing overview of my google play console and also the screenshot when I try to search my app via link.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Br4ex.png)

I have tried viewing my app from these methods

1. Directly searching by application's name
2. Searching by application's name in inverted commas("")
3. Searching by "pub: package name" method
4. Tried to view by "View on google play" text button which is on dashboard on google play console
5. Tried from opening google play store from browser and trying all the steps above
6. Cleared cache and data of play store (mobile app) then searched
   [image]
   Also I view my inbox of google play console and gmail which is provided on google play console daily to see any updates but there are no updates.

Comment: What happens if you open a Play Store web page of an arbitrary app and then replace the package name in the URL with the one from your app?

Comment: I get a message "We're sorry, the requested URL was not found on this server."

Comment: To my experience this means that the app is not accessible to anyone which contradicts your screenshot that shows that it should be available via Google Play.